# How to set the first day of the week to Saturday in postgresql for Jalali dates

Tags: postgresql, metabase

I have to write a query in metabase that outputs the records whose done_date falls within the current week and in Jalali calendar, the first day of the week is Saturday. I need to change the first day of the week to saturday to be able to write a correct `WHERE` statement in my query. *I do not have access to postgres.conf*.

Here is the `WHERE` statement of my query:

```sql
WHERE (("tasks"."finished_date")::DATE >= DATE_TRUNC('week', NOW()))
    AND (("tasks"."finished_date")::DATE < DATE_TRUNC('week', NOW()+ INTERVAL '1 week'))
```

I have tried subtracting intervals but it's not helping.

Comment: Subtracting two days should get you to Saturday from Monday. Can you show the query that doesn't work, maybe with some sample data?

Comment: It might be helpful to install the [Jalali calendar](https://github.com/teamappir/jalali_utils) extension. I never needed it so do not have experience with it, but I think that is where I would start.